# How to use javascript execCommand to create rich text editor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome, execcommand

I have created the HTML and javascript files. I have included a bold icon using fontawesome.com, and I made a button using the icon. Using execCommand I have tried to make the bold button edit selected text in the text area after the button is clicked. But the code is not working.

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>
          Editor
      </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
      <script src="script.js"> </script>
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f7ac85e141.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="navBar" id="heading-container" contentEditable="true">
                <button onclick="execCmd('bold');">
                    <i class="fas fa-bold"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </header>
        <textarea id="myTextArea"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur. </textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
function execCmd(command) {
  let field = document.getElementById('myTextArea');
  field.document.execCommand(command, false, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

document.execCommand use in contenteditable not in textarea, so:

```
function execCmd(command) {
  let field = document.getElementById('heading-container');
  field.document.execCommand(command, false, null);
}
```

btw execcommand is obsolete, so try use range replace it. or you can use pure dom in this case, just like @Mike Poole 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are going about making the text bold in a complicated manner. I would go about it using the `getElementById` method:

```js
function makeBold(){
  document.getElementById('myTextArea').style.fontWeight = '900';
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f7ac85e141.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
          <div class="navBar" id="heading-container" contentEditable="true">
              <button onclick="makeBold();">
                  <i class="fas fa-bold"></i>
              </button>
          </div>
        <textarea id="myTextArea"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur. </textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I decided to have a look at [the spec](http://w3c.github.io/editing/execCommand.html) for this to see if it specifically said it wasn't supposed to work on `textarea`s, and it looks like you probably don't want to use `execCommand` because of this warning at the top of the spec:

> This spec is incomplete and it is not expected that it will advance beyond draft status. Authors should not use most of these features directly, but instead use JavaScript editing libraries. The features described in this document are not implemented consistently or fully by user agents, and it is not expected that this will change in the foreseeable future. There is currently no alternative to some execCommand actions related to clipboard content and contentEditable=true is often used to draw the caret and move the caret in the block direction as well as a few minor subpoints. This spec is to meant to help implementations in standardizing these existing features. It is predicted that in the future both specs will be replaced by Content Editable and Input Events.

Original below:

---

There are a  few reasons why the version you have doesn't work.

#### First

`field` doesn't have a `document` property, if you look in the browser console you'll see something like `field.document is undefined`. You need to use just [`document.execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) where `document` is the global document object.

You could use an `iframe` tag surrounding the editable text if you want to. Then the `iframe` would have a [`contentDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument) property. I don't see a good reason to do that though.

#### Second

You need to prevent the default action of the `onmousedown` event from the button removing the selection.

```
<button onmousedown="event.preventDefault();" onclick="execCmd('bold');">
    <i class="fas fa-bold"></i>
</button>
```

#### Third

It still doesn't seem to work on `textarea`s and I'm not sure why. The [`document.execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) page I linked above has a [link to an example](https://codepen.io/chrisdavidmills/full/gzYjag/) of using `execCommand` that includes "bold". They use a `div` with `contentEditable="true"` set on it. I got it to work myself with one of those but the `textarea` still didn't work. Maybe there's another event that needs to be stopped? No idea.